# Por que minha variável é null?

Tags: javascript, java, regex

Estou traduzindo uma função de Java para JS, a lógica permanece a mesma mas os resultados são diferentes. 
[No teste da expressão regular](https://regex101.com/r/yW0hP4/1), retorna **match** quando testo `40kb` mas ao compilar o código obtenho um null numa linha não específicada. 
Por que quando testo "2kb" não é null e com "40kb" obtenho erro no JS?

Log

```
Error:
TypeError: getNumbers is null
```

JS

```
 function process(val) {
        var isPeso = "(?:k|m|g)b$";
        var normalizado = val.trim().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
        var unidade = "";
        var numberPattern = "\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|(Livre)/i";

        var myArray = normalizado.match(isPeso);
        if (myArray != null) {
            unidade = myArray;

            var getNumbers = val.match(numberPattern);
            var i;
            var valores = [];
            for (i = 0; i < getNumbers.length - 1; i++) {
                valores.push((getNumbers[i]))
            }

            var out = "";
            //Caso [X ou superior]
            if (normalizado.indexOf("superior") > -1) {
                return valores[0] + unidade + " ou superior";
            }
            //Caso [X até Y] e [até Y]
            else if (normalizado.indexOf("até") > -1) {
                //Caso [até Y]
                if (valores.length == 1) {
                    out = "até " + valores[0];
                }
                //Caso [X até Y]
                else {
                    out = valores[0] + " até " + valores[1];
                }
            }

            //Caso [X ou Y] ou [X ou Y ou ...]
            else if (normalizado.indexOf("ou") > -1 || normalizado.indexOf("/") > -1) {
                out = valores[0];
                for (i = 1; i < valores.length -1; i++) {
                    out += valores[i];
                }
            }
            //Caso livre
            else if (normalizado.indexOf("*") > -1 || normalizado.indexOf("livre") > -1) {
                out = "Livre";
            }
            //Caso X
            else {
                if (valores.length > 0) {
                    out = valores[0];
                }
            }
            if (out.length == 0 || out == null) {
                return "";
            }
            return out + unidade;
        }
    }
```

Java

```
public class IntervaloHandler implements LanguageInterface{
    public static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?|(Livre)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     public String normalizar(String in) throws LanguageHandler.NormalizarExcception {
            //Trim e LowerCase
            String normalizado = in.trim().toLowerCase(new Locale("pt", "BR"));

            //Identifica a unidade
            String unidade = "";

            Pattern tempoPattern = Pattern.compile("s$");
            Matcher tempoMatcher = tempoPattern.matcher(normalizado);

            Pattern bytesPattern = Pattern.compile("(k|m|g)b$");
            Matcher matcher = bytesPattern.matcher(normalizado);

            //Bytes (PESO)
            if(matcher.find()){
                unidade = matcher.group();
            }

            //Encontra os valores e formata
            ArrayList<String> valores = new ArrayList<>();
            Matcher m = NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(in);
            while(m.find()){
                valores.add(m.group().replaceAll(" ", ""));
            }
            String out = "";





            //Caso [X ou superior]
            if(normalizado.contains("superior")){
                return String.format("%s%s ou superior", valores.get(0), unidade);
            }
            //Caso [X até Y] e [até Y]
            else if(normalizado.contains("até")){
                //Caso [até Y]
                if(valores.size() == 1){
                    out = String.format("até %s", valores.get(0));
                }
                //Caso [X até Y]
                else{
                    out = String.format("%s até %s", valores.get(0), valores.get(1));
                }
            }
            //Caso [X ou Y] ou [X ou Y ou ...]
            else if(normalizado.contains("ou") || normalizado.contains("/")){
                out = valores.get(0);
                for(int i=1; i < valores.size(); i++){
                    out += String.format("/%s", valores.get(i));
                }
            }
            //Caso livre
            else if(normalizado.contains("*") || normalizado.contains("livre")) {
                out = "Livre";
            }
            //Caso X
            else {
                if(valores.size() > 0)
                    out = valores.get(0);
            }




            //Coloca a unidade no final
            return out.isEmpty() ? "" : String.format("%s%s", out, unidade);
        }
}
```

Comment: Tentou usar `/\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|(Livre)/i` para a expressão regular e substituir `var getNumbers = numberPattern.match(val);` por `var getNumbers = val.match(numberPattern);`?

Comment: O erro continua o mesmo.

Comment: Você está usando a expressão regular como literal, assim: `var numberPattern = /\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|(Livre)/i;`? Ou como string?

Comment: Estava usando como String, como literal não obtive mais o erro! Ainda não obtive o resultado esperado mas obg.

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado? Atualize sua pergunta que talvez consigo lhe ajudar, daí posto uma resposta.

Comment: São somente alguns exemplos de casos, provavelmente não está entrando no laço dos respectivos return's, irei testar  
1) input = "20 Mb", expected = "20mb"; 2) input = "20 Mb ou 10mb", expected = "20/10mb"; 3) input = "aTé 10Mb", expected = "até 10mb";

Comment: É, neste caso teria que verificar toda sua função, ela está com alguns problemas, até mesmo de lógica. Você consegue resolver tudo com expressões regulares, como se utilizar agrupamentos e pegar as partes que deseja. Neste caso, teste e se não der conta poste suas dúvidas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua variável é nula por que a expressão regular não "casa" nada nos exemplos, nem mesmo `2kb` funcionou por aqui.

Ela não combina com nenhuma parte da entrada por que não é uma expressão regular válida da forma que é declarada, ou seja, a sintaxe está incorreta.

Prefira usar expressões regulares [literais](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression). Então, no lugar disto:

```
"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|(Livre)/i"
```

use isto:

```
/\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|(Livre)/i
```

Mas por que? Bem, esta `\` é um carácter de escape em string, então prefira literais por ser mais elegante e até mesmo mais legível e simples de representar a expressão, do contrário você iria precisar disto:

```
"\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?|(Livre)\/i"
```

ou isto:

```
var reg = new RegExp("\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?|(Livre)", "i");
```

Bem mais conveniente usar literais, não é? =)

Veja um exemplo da forma literal:

```js
function process(val) {
    var isPeso = "(?:k|m|g)b$";
    var normalizado = val.trim().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
    var unidade = "";
    var numberPattern = /\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|(Livre)/i;

    var myArray = normalizado.match(isPeso);
    if (myArray != null) {
        unidade = myArray;

        var getNumbers = val.match(numberPattern);
        var i;
        var valores = [];
        for (i = 0; i < getNumbers.length - 1; i++) {
            valores.push(getNumbers[i]);
        }

        var out = "";
        //Caso [X ou superior]
        if (normalizado.indexOf("superior") > -1) {
            return valores[0] + unidade + " ou superior";
        }
        //Caso [X até Y] e [até Y]
        else if (normalizado.indexOf("até") > -1) {
            //Caso [até Y]
            if (valores.length == 1) {
                out = "até " + valores[0];
            }
            //Caso [X até Y]
            else {
                out = valores[0] + " até " + valores[1];
            }
        }

        //Caso [X ou Y] ou [X ou Y ou ...]
        else if (normalizado.indexOf("ou") > -1 || normalizado.indexOf("/") > -1) {
            out = valores[0];
            for (i = 1; i < valores.length - 1; i++) {
                out += valores[i];
            }
        }
        //Caso livre
        else if (normalizado.indexOf("*") > -1 || normalizado.indexOf("livre") > -1) {
            out = "Livre";
        }
        //Caso X
        else {
            if (valores.length > 0) {
                out = valores[0];
            }
        }
        if (out.length == 0 || out == null) {
            return "";
        }
        
        return out + unidade;
    }
}
function test() {
    var val = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var result = process(val);
    document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "Resultado: entrada: " + val + " | saida: " + result;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" />
<button onclick="test()">GO</button>
<p>
    <span id="span">Resultado: </span>
</p>
```

E um usando string "escapadas":

```js
function process(val) {
    var isPeso = "(?:k|m|g)b$";
    var normalizado = val.trim().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
    var unidade = "";
    var numberPattern = "\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?|(Livre)\/i";

    var myArray = normalizado.match(isPeso);
    if (myArray != null) {
        unidade = myArray;

        var getNumbers = val.match(numberPattern);
        var i;
        var valores = [];
        for (i = 0; i < getNumbers.length - 1; i++) {
            valores.push(getNumbers[i]);
        }

        var out = "";
        //Caso [X ou superior]
        if (normalizado.indexOf("superior") > -1) {
            return valores[0] + unidade + " ou superior";
        }
        //Caso [X até Y] e [até Y]
        else if (normalizado.indexOf("até") > -1) {
            //Caso [até Y]
            if (valores.length == 1) {
                out = "até " + valores[0];
            }
            //Caso [X até Y]
            else {
                out = valores[0] + " até " + valores[1];
            }
        }

        //Caso [X ou Y] ou [X ou Y ou ...]
        else if (normalizado.indexOf("ou") > -1 || normalizado.indexOf("/") > -1) {
            out = valores[0];
            for (i = 1; i < valores.length - 1; i++) {
                out += valores[i];
            }
        }
        //Caso livre
        else if (normalizado.indexOf("*") > -1 || normalizado.indexOf("livre") > -1) {
            out = "Livre";
        }
        //Caso X
        else {
            if (valores.length > 0) {
                out = valores[0];
            }
        }
        if (out.length == 0 || out == null) {
            return "";
        }
        
        return out + unidade;
    }
}
function test() {
    var val = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var result = process(val);
    document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "Resultado: entrada: " + val + " | saida: " + result;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" />
<button onclick="test()">GO</button>
<p>
    <span id="span">Resultado: </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigada. Por motivos desconhecidos, o  Nashorn não está executando esse script (`javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot get property "length" of null in <eval> at line number 1`).

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais bom, usando o primeiro examplo, tratando a função para ser avaliada pelo nashorn, funcionou OK. Entrada `aa20kb`, saída `20kb`. Qual foi a entrada que você testou?

Comment: "50kb" e obtenho o `ScriptException`

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais veja se este [gist](https://gist.github.com/brunocesarsilva/2d053889a8f6056e28c7) lhe ajuda.